# Need Help Writing SVN Code Review Tool

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, svn, visualsvn-server

I am working on writing a SVN Code Review Tool for my team.  We use VisualSVN Server on the server side and TortoiseSVN on the client side.

What I am trying to do write a Post-Commit hook that will open up a web browser that will show an MVC webpage for a user to configure a review.

I've tried :

```
start http://www.google.com
```

but the commit works fine but doesn't open a new browser.

Answer (score 2):

SVN hooks are server side.  Your hook is trying to launch a browser on the SVN server, not the user's machine.

Answer (score 1):

As Randy has already mentioned: server-side hook scripts run **on server side**! Since you use TortoiseSVN on client-side you can try using [client-side hooks](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks).

However, these hooks should be deployed on each developer's machine and the feature exists in TortoiseSVN only. In other words, those who use command-line or another SVN client won't see the browser after commit.